# Multilevel modeling

Tags: random, stata, effects, hierarchical

I want to look at the change in the percentage of income savings measured in dollars using repeated measures data for older adults. I want to compare three groups based on their father's occupation while growing up.

I want to estimate different slopes and intercepts for the three groups. For example: group A is subjects whose father's were blue-collar; group B is subjects whose fathers were white-collar; group C is subjects whose fathers were other types of workers. I have repeated measures for 10 annual surveys and subjects reported how much of their income they saved. I want to see if the intercept and trajectory differ for the three groups.

This is what I come up with but I am not sure if this gets at the appropriate verbal explanation.

m1

```
xtmixed savings time || subjects:, var
```

m1 looks at the impact of time on savings and estimates intercepts and slopes for each subject.

m2

```
xtmixed savings time##fathers_occupation || subjects:, var
```

Does m2 examine the differences in the intercept and slope for the two groups? Or do I need to add `fathers_occupation` to the right side of `||` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it in the right part, unless you think the effect of `fathers_occupation` on `savings` is different between all the subjects. m2 estimates different intercepts for each subject and then the `time##fathers_occupation` estimates the slopes of fathers_occupation in each measurement (time) group of subjects.

I don't know your data but I think it's very unlikely to have different effects for `fathers_occupation` for all the different subjects, so I think you could rely on the simpler, random intercept model with the interaction term, as specified by m2.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Are you suggesting for m2: xtmixed savings time##fathers_occupation

Comment: yes, I was suggesting: `xtmixed savings time##fathers_occupation || subjects:, var`